# Sharepoint- Client Object Model - Javascript - How to check if a particular file with same name exists in a document library folder

Tags: javascript, document-library, client-object-model, sharepoint-library

I am using javascript sharepoint 2013.

I want to know how to check if a file exists in a folder, before i upload.

Here's my code

```
// Folder Name - folder into which I need to upload
   var FolderName = "Images";
// Root Folder Name
   var rootfolder = '/Image Library/' + FolderName;
// Get the context and Web
   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
// These are the files which I need to upload into the "Images" folder of the document library
    var files = document.getElementById(UploadFiles).files;
```

Now I need to check if the file already exists in the "Images" folder. 
If it exists , i need to throw a message , "Äre you sure to overwrite?"

I am pretty new to Sharepoint, please suggest if I need to write a CAML query or some other way to achieve this.

Please suggest. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could consider the following approaches to determine whether file exists or not.

### Query based

You could construct CAML query to find list item by its Url as demonstrated below:

```
var listTitle = 'Documents';
var fileUrl  = '/project/shared documents/orders/order.docx';

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var qry = new SP.CamlQuery();
qry.set_viewXml('<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FileRef"/><Value Type="Url">' + fileUrl + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
var items = list.getItems(qry);
ctx.load(items);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
  var fileFound = (items.get_count() > 0);
}, 
function(sender, args) {
  console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

### SP.Web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl Method

Use [SP.Web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246729(v=office.15).aspx) to return the file object located at the specified server-relative URL.

If file does not exists the exception `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` will be thrown:

```
function getFileExists(fileUrl,complete,error)
{
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var file = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrl);
   ctx.load(file);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
      complete(true);
   }, 
   function(sender, args) {
     if (args.get_errorTypeName() === "System.IO.FileNotFoundException") {
         complete(false);
     }
     else {
       error(args);
     }  
   });
}
```

Usage

```
getFileExists('/project/shared documents/orders/order.docx',
  function(fileFound){
     console.log(fileFound);
  },
  function(error)
  {
     console.log(args.get_message());
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try getting the file and use the success/error callback in executeQueryAsync...

```
var myCtx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var myFile = myCtx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(/<site>/<lib>/<filename w/ extension>);
myCtx.load(myFile);


myCtx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    // success handler, if you made it here, the file exists
}, function(sender, args) {
    // error handler, if you made it here something else went wrong...
    if (args.get_message() == "File Not Found.") {
        //if you get here, the file didn't exist
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are some option:

Uncheck overwrite by default
http://planet-sharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/sharepoint-2010-set-overwrite-existing.html

jQuery option
http://vegardstromsoy.blogspot.se/2011/05/jquery-to-override-sharepoint-ootb.html

Comment: I just want to check if a specific file already exists. Using Javascript code. Please suggest. Thanks again!